# Success cause passion more than passion cause success

Tags: social-psychology

What are the good psychology studies about this hypothesis ?

From an evolutionary standpoint, it would makes sense on a group level. When a few people starts doing a new thing, if one a them sees that he is better at it than the other directly around him, he would have a greater probability to like doing this new thing. The group would be composed of more specialized people each good at what they do, and therefore with better surviving chances.

Where is it possible to find resources about this subject ?

Comment: "to like doing this new thing" does not really constitute passion, that's the weakest part of your hypothesis. perhaps what you're saying is, repatriation of doing something is strongly related to how successful one is at doing it

Comment: Voted to close because the question lacks sufficient definition and context. Is it a reinforcement learning question? A self-regulation question? An evolutionary psychology question?